# Using different list for names of each point in highcharts in javascripts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have three arrays coming from a json dictionary in js in this way:

```
var a=[]
var b=[]
var c=[]
var d = JSON.parse('{{ dictionary | safe}}');
for (var key in d)  {  
    b.push(d[key]['score']);
    a.push(key);
    c.push(d[key]['text']);
}
```

I managed to have a chart using highchat is this way:

```
 $('#container0').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Daily News {{ name }}',
                x: -20 
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: News.',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: a
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Scores'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: colors[3]
                }]
            },
        series: [{
                allowPointSelect: true,
                name: 'news score',
                data: b,
                color: colors[2]
            }]
        });
```

When I mouse over/click on each pint, I get the value. I want to modify it in order to show the value from the array c. I tried many ways but nothing worked. I do appreciate your helps.

Comment: You tried with sort()?

Comment: I want the texts (array c) appears for each point in my chart. What is with sort?

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo with hardcoded data, only for testing  ?

Answer (score 0):

Name for a point can be set through setting property `name` for a data point. It can be done as presented in [API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.data.name), so each point is an object with `name` property, like:

```
    series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            y: 1
        }, 
        ...
```

In your case array `[nameString, value]` will work as well.

```
    series: [{
        data: [
            ['Point 1', 1],
            ...
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fnmncx6h/

So, for your code you could use something like this:

```
var a=[]
var b=[]
var d = JSON.parse('{{ dictionary | safe}}');
for (var key in d)  {  
    b.push([d[key]['text'], d[key]['score']]);
    a.push(key);
}
```

and later use `b` as data for series.

To set tooltip's text you can use one of many formatting functions provided in API - e.g. [headerFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.headerFormat),  [pointFormatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormatter).